# How to forbideen updating model in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have nested controller like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
   <div ng-controller="ChildController"></div>
</div>
```

Inside Child controller there is function:

```
$scope.isStatus = function() {
    return function(item) {
}};
```

This function is used in `ng-repeat`.

So, problem is when I modify model of controller `MainController` it reload model of `ChildController`, It means that function `isStatus()` works again and reload model. How to fix it?

Comment: short of using one time binding (`{{::isStatus}}`), you can't "selectively" only process some items for binding.  when the digest cycle runs and the outer div is re-rendered, the inner div is re-rendered as well, which means it's elements all have to be re-evaluated.

Comment: I did not get it, what do you mean? What changes I should make?

Comment: I did not provide an answer because this behavior is by design, and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use controllerAs syntax to avoid this

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController as main">
       <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
   <ul ng-repeat ="item in child.item">
</div>
    </div>
```

And in js

```
function ChildController (){
 var vm = this;
vm.isStatus = function() {
    return function(item) {
}};
}
```

you can see more infomation in here

> https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controllers

Comment: This isn't going to help.  the problem is with the digest cycle;  when the outer HTML is re-rendered, the inner HTML is re-rendered as well, causing the bindings to be re-evaluated, no matter what scope they are bound to, or how the controller is declared.